# How can i keybinding each on/ off word wrap in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

i knew alt + z is keybind of wordwrap on/off.
I want to keybind each on/off setting separately.

```
    {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+q",
    "Editor.wordWrap": "on"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+e",
    "Editor.wordWrap": "off"
}
```

i tried this, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in your `keybindings.json` - this assumes you are starting with wordwrap disabled in your settings.  If it is enabled, the following keybindings are reversed but still work.  Just swap the `keys` for your case.

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+q",
  "command": "editor.action.toggleWordWrap",   // wrap will become enabled
  "when": "!editorWordWrap"        // when word wrap is disabled in settings
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+e",
  "command": "editor.action.toggleWordWrap",   // word wrap will become disabled
  "when": "editorWordWrap"         // when word wrap is enabled in settings
}
```